# Creating checksums for generated files in maven when executing mvn package

Tags: maven, checksum

I have a maven project to create a zip file which can be used to upgrade the applications we distribute. When `mvn package` is executed this will gather required dependencies and bundle with some PowerShell scripts which does the upgrade. I want to create a checksum for the generated zip file.

When i searched over internet i got two solutions one is to use `-DcreateChecksum=true` option for the `mvn install` plugin. This zip file is big and we don't want to copy this to maven repository hence we don't execute this goal. Another option is using `checksum-maven-plugin`, but this will create checksum for artifacts which i don't want. It also has a command line option `mvn checksum:file -Dfile=some-file.zip` but this has to be executed manually. I want to add this to my pom so we don't have to manually create checksum. Is there any clean way other than creating a script to create checksum and calling it.

Comment: Why not publishing it into a maven repository...and afterwards deploy from there...Apart from that: What do you mean by `big`?

Comment: The packed files are around 1GB and they are a zip of already existing artifacts with some scripts. It will be waste of space in build server and waste of time as it would take lot of time to upload these files. We just package a tagged version and distribute.

Comment: If the upload takes so much time your systems are to slow..I have had a build which produces 10x times size packages...and we just deployed them to a repository manager and it makes life easier to go the default path...and disk space is cheap...The space in the build server I don't understand cause it's only stored temporarily...so ?

Comment: I know the systems are slow. Convincing management to upgrade their hardware is well above my pay grade. If I ask for an upgrade they just ask me to do it manually as it takes less than 5 mins. I am just a lazy ass and don't want to do it manually every time I release something. I will find a workaround using an ANT task or some custom script.